# Authentication Credentials with the SendPulse API for Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, smtp

I'm using the SendPulse client library written in node for smtp. Here's a snippet from their example.js:

```
var API_USER_ID="USER_ID"
var API_SECRET="USER_SECRET"

var TOKEN_STORAGE="/tmp/"

sendpulse.init(API_USER_ID,API_SECRET,TOKEN_STORAGE);
```

I've tried using my email address that I've created the account with, and the password they gave me on the SMTP settings page, for user_id and user_secret, respectively. When I run the code, I get this error message:

> { error: 'invalid_request',   error_description: 'The request is
>   missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value,
>   includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check
>   the "access token" parameter.',   message: 'The request is missing a
>   required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a
>   parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the "access
>   token" parameter.',   error_code: 1 }

However, it doesn't seem to matter what you do, you'll always get that error message. You can run `sendpulse.ini();` and still get that message.

My question is, what are the proper credentials to use the SendPulse node library? The smtp settings page also gives me a public key, not sure what to do with that. I've noticed this library is a year old, is it out of date? Your help is much appreciated. I'm at the end of a very big project, this is the last hurdle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "ID" and "Secret" from the https://login.sendpulse.com/settings/ page, go to "API" tab and enable "Activate REST API".

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify the issue for future people, I was going to this settings page: https://login.sendpulse.com/smtp/index/settings/api/1. My guess was this was v1 of the api. Also, "text" is a required field for sending an email, you can't only send an html version. Otherwise you'll get an error message back. But it's working now.

Comment: The API Documentation from Send Pulse is horrible.